# Resize CIDER minibuffer for evaluated expressions

Tags: macos, emacs, clojure, cider

I'm using CIDER to connect to a Clojure REPL.

I would like to be able to control the font size of the output when I evaluate expressions at the REPL (`cider-eval-last-sexp`).  Example of the current, small size is shown here:
[image: screenshot]

It's the very bottom line I'd like to enlarge.

I can control the "normal" (non-CIDER) minibuffer using the following:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-setup)
(defun my-minibuffer-setup ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
       '((default :height 1.5))))
```

however, while this works for all other minibuffer operations (M-x, etc.), it doesn't work for evaluated Clojure expressions -- they are displayed with the old/smaller size.  I'm on the Emacs installed by Homebrew Cask, 24.3.1.

Comment: Looking at your modeline (`nREPL/i`) I seen you still haven't removed the old `nrepl` package (which CIDER succeeded). That won't solve your problem, but it's definitely a good idea.

Comment: Thank you @BozhidarBatsov, I just did that.  And, nice article! http://batsov.com/articles/2012/02/19/package-management-in-emacs-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about enlarging the minibuffer, but you can also evaluate the form with C-c C-p. That pops the result up in a temporary buffer and pretty-prints it to boot.

Comment: Thanks, the pretty-printing feature is nice to know about!